# auto-py-to-exe --- Resolving the path of the exe files and not it instance in AppData\Local\Temp\

Tags: auto-py-to-exe

I have the following lines in my .py that i convert to an exe one file window based ;

source_path = Path(file).resolve()
source_dir = source_path.parent

I use the pass to access files as config files, so i just need to keep those files in the same folder as the exe.
The problem is that once running the exe that has been generated by AUTO-PY-TO-EXE it resolve a path here d\AppData\Local\Temp_MEI209402\ .

Why is that, what did i miss to avoid this issue?
Anyone has encountered the same problem ?

I have try to use different way to get the the path, expecting getting the right path whil running the exe